# Merge PDF by streams

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, pdf, itext

I am in trouble with a `.ashx` which should merge some PDF memory-stream, in a simplest case, where I have in output only one stream, the output PDF stream are corrupted, but when I call another ashx which get in output only the single stream works, what I miss in the following code?

I collect memory-streams:

```
Dim streamDocument As MemoryStream = FumForm.CreatePdfDocument(context, _fumForm, _formTemplate, _match)
lReader.Add(New PdfReader(streamDocument))
```

then I would like append all pdf pages in an other pdf:

```
Dim document As Document = New Document(PageSize.A4, 0, 0, 0, 0)
Dim writer As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, context.Response.OutputStream)
document.Open()

For Each r As PdfReader In lReader
  For i As Integer = 1 To r.NumberOfPages
    Dim page As PdfImportedPage = writer.GetImportedPage(r, i)
    document.Add(Image.GetInstance(page))

  Next
Next

Dim filename = String.Format("{0}{1}.pdf", "pippo", "test")
document.Close()
context.Response.Clear()
context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
context.Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=""" & filename & """")
context.Response.Flush()
context.Response.Close()
context.Response.End()
```

`CreatePdfDocument` works well, and have this signature

```
static public MemoryStream CreatePdfDocument(HttpContext context, 
                                             FumForm form, 
                                             FumFormTemplate formTemplate, 
                                             Match match)
```

Any help will be really appreciated

Comment: I think it is a very bad idea to clear and change headers of the `context.Response` after the whole PDF has already been written to `context.Response.OutputStream`.

Comment: @mkl damn, you are right :) please add your answer

Comment: @AlexisPigeon ty Alex i will refine the string format, bwt the string was not a problem ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code first writes the whole PDF to `context.Response.OutputStream`

```
Dim document As Document = New Document(PageSize.A4, 0, 0, 0, 0)
Dim writer As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, context.Response.OutputStream)
...
document.Close()
```

and *thereafter* clears and changes headers of the `context.Response`

```
context.Response.Clear()
context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
context.Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=""" & filename & """")
```

To work correctly, all response object clearing and header manipulations have to be finished before the data may be written to the response stream.